# Request the SVN to check the original project file for updates that were made to the file that was not checked out

Tags: svn, version-control, phpstorm, tortoisesvn

We are currently setting up an SVN, using Tortoise SVN and PhpStorm, at our company, and we are worried about if we needed a quick change and went directly into the project file **without checking out** and made a change and commit it. We noticed that the other users that have the file checked out will not receive the update when they update the project.

Is there a way to update the SVN to look at the original project file and take note of the changes so that the other users can receive the files when they update their project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the modifications were not committed to the repository it means that they were not published. You can think as these modifications do not even exist.

You must commit the local modifications so that other could update their working copies and see these changes.

Read the documentation:

- [Version Control Basics](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.version-control-basics.html)
- [How the Working Copy Works](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.track-repos)
- [Basic Work Cycle](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html)